# SDL_Texture in QWidget

Tags: qt, textures, sdl, qwidget, qimage

I found a way to convert a SDL_Surface to a QImage.

```
QImage MainWindow::createFromSurface(SDL_Surface * surf)
{
    QImage img(static_cast<uchar*>(surf->pixels), surf->w, surf->h, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    return img;
}
```

Is there a way to convert a SDL_Texture?

Comment: what do you want? SDL_Texture to QImage instead of SDL_Surface to QImage?

Comment: Yes, i want to display a SDL_Texture in a QImage.